# How to get a Django application view on 127.0.0.1:8000?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and was learning about views and urls. This is from the official Django documentation.

urls.py ->

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

views.py ->

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

So if my Django server is running on default port 8000 and if I type the address **127.0.0.1:8000/polls** where polls is my app name I will be redirected to a view saying **Hello, world. You're at the polls index.**
I want my server to display a view when I type in the url **127.0.0.1:8000** without the app name. If this is possible, how should I do it?

Comment: The code you've shown already does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to change it at the main `urls.py`. This file is maybe in the `mysite` folder. So change

`url(r'^polls', include('polls.urls')),`

to

`url(r'^', include('polls.urls')),`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the **url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),** to your project's **urls.py** not in app's urls.py.